# My theme didn't appear sidebar area

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I tried to customize my WordPress theme but it shows this error.

> Your theme has 2 widget areas, but this particular page doesn’t display them.
>   You can navigate to other pages on your site while using the Customizer to view > and edit the widgets displayed on those pages.

First, there didn't show widget area so I Add this code for that then it shows widget and but now show the above error.

```
if (function_exists("register_sidebar")) {
register_sidebar();
}
```

This is my function.php file how can I solve this issue. Do I want to change any other page?

```
<?php

/**
 * Enqueues scripts and styles.
 *
 */
if (function_exists("register_sidebar")) {
register_sidebar();
}

function umk_enque_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'normalize-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normal.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'umkthemes-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'landmark', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/landmark-map.css' );

    // wp_enqueue_script( 'umkthemes-script', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/responsiveslides.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );  
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'umk_enque_scripts' );

function umkthemes_setup() {
    add_theme_support ('menus');
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
    // set_post_thumbnail_size( 273 , 146 );

    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary_menu' => 'Main navigation',
    ) );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'umkthemes_setup' );



// Our custom post type function
function create_posttype() {

     register_post_type( 'sale',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Sale' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Sale' ),
                'all_items' => __('All Sales', 'umkthemes'), /* the all items menu item */
                'add_new' => __('Add New Sale', 'umkthemes'), /* The add new menu item */
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Sale', 'umkthemes'), /* Add New Display Title */
                'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'jointstheme' ), /* Edit Dialog */
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Sale', 'umkthemes'), /* Edit Display Title */
                'new_item' => __('New  Sale', 'umkthemes'), /* New Display Title */
                'view_item' => __('View Sale', 'umkthemes'), /* View Display Title */
                'search_items' => __('Search Sale', 'umkthemes'), /* Search Custom Type Title */
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'sale'),
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', )
        )
    );
}




// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

Comment: This should be `if(!function_exists("register_sidebar")) { /* Your Code */ }`

Comment: @Pim No it shouldn't. Why would that help?

Comment: Considering that `register_sidebar()` has been a part of core since 2.2.0, really it's rather strange change to check for it's existence at all... @RUC... `register_sidebar()` creates a new area for widgets, but it does not display it. You'll need a call to [`dynamic_sidebar()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) for that.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Your theme has 2 widget areas, but this particular page doesn’t
>   display them. You can navigate to other pages on your site while using
>   the Customizer to view > and edit the widgets displayed on those
>   pages.

This is beacuse theme might be using conditional loading of widgets on particular pages i.e.,

```
if ( is_single() ) :
  get_sidebar( 'primary' );
endif;
```

And if you are in a page that doesn't support widgets, WordPress will display that message

Remove this code in your functions.php file

```
  if (function_exists("register_sidebar")) {
    register_sidebar();
    }
```

and include the file containing that function ( register_sidebar() )

like: `require_once WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/includes/function-file.php';`

Or you can register sidebar directly in your functions.php file like:

```
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_register_sidebars' );
        function my_register_sidebars() {
        /* Register the 'primary' sidebar. */
            register_sidebar(
                array(
                    'id'            => 'primary',
                    'name'          => __( 'Primary Sidebar' ),
                    'description'   => __( 'A short description of the sidebar.' ),
                    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
                    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
                    'after_title'   => '</h3>',
                )
            );
            /* Repeat register_sidebar() code for additional sidebars. */
        }
```

and to display sidebar in your theme template ( usually you'll need to create a sidebar.php file ) paste following code

```
<div id="sidebar-primary" class="sidebar">
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary' ); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <!-- Time to add some widgets! -->
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please Function.php file

```
function twentyseventeen_widgets_init() {   
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Blog Sidebar', 'twentyseventeen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar on blog posts and archive pages.', 'twentyseventeen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );    
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentyseventeen_widgets_init' );
```

then after calling any template otherwise any files(header.php, footer.php etc)

also, add any widget in widget page in admin the name is 'Bolg sidebar'